# How to disable disable QScrollbar context menu in Qt (windows xp)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a Qt application running on a windows XP machine and i am trying to finally disable the context menu which pops up when right clicking on a scroll bar (with the "scroll down" and "page up" etc. .. ) inside this application.

I tried the following things, which didn't work:

```
ui->scrollArea->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);            
ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);

ui->scrollArea->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);       
ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::PreventContextMenu);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to disable horizontal (not vertical) scroll bar context menu? `horizontalScrollBar()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);` works fine for me.

Comment: hi hank, than you for the comment - in fact i am trying to disable them for all scrollbars (the horizontal one is just an example). I just found out that you are correct - it works for all 'standard' scrollbars - but i use one which is created inside a scrollarea (or at a side of a tableview) whith the flag `Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded` on. The Scrollbar inside this seem to ignore the ContextMenuPolicy, even if I grab them an explicitly set it with the given code ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never found out why it didn't really worked in my context (it seems it has to do with nested widgets and objects) but I found a solution which is something like a sledge-hammer method but works for me:

```
foreach(QObject *widget, qApp->allWidgets())
{
    QScrollBar *scrollBar = dynamic_cast<QScrollBar*>(widget);
    if(scrollBar)
    {
        scrollBar->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    }
}
```

This disables context menus of scrollbars (or other objects if modified) in the whole application once at startup.